# ASSERT failure in QList<T>::operator[]: "index out of range"

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcreator

Уже голову сломал. Итак, есть `QList<QString>` или `QStringList` (не влияет на ошибку),

В одной функции я его создаю и отправляю в поле класса:

```
void AddDialog::onOkBtn(){
    QList<QString> fields;
    QString name = ui->itemName->text();
    QString count = ui->itemCount->text();
    QString price = ui->itemPrice->text();
    QString date = ui->itemDate->text().replace('.', '-');

    fields.push_back(name);
    fields.push_back(count);
    fields.push_back(price);
    fields.push_back(date);
    qDebug() << fields.size();

    this->fields = fields;

    emit accepted();
}
```

после этого в другом классе есть функция которая должна этот `QList<QString>` обрабатывать:

```
void MainWindow::refresh()
{
    QList<QString> fields = addWindow.getFields();
    qDebug() << fields.size() << fields[0];

}
```

(`getFields` лишь возвращает переменную fields):

```
QStringList AddDialog::getFields()
{
    return this->fields;
}
```

Проблема в том, что когда я хочу получит любой элемент из fields с помощью `[]` или `.at()` 
программа вылетает:

`ASSERT failure in QList<T>::operator[]: "index out of range", file C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore/qlist.h, line 552`

тогда я подумал, может мой QList не дозодит до места использования, и решил просто вывести его длину:

```
qDebug() << fields.size();
```

Но! вместо числа 0 или 4 (я записывал в этот список 4 строки)
я получаю сначала 0, а потом 4:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопросы:

1) почему я получаю 2 числа в консоль?

2) почему сначала 0, а потом 4,

3) как мне сделать так, чтоб я получал просто 4 и спокойно работал со списком?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Ну для начала очень странно то что вы возвращаете разные типы. И покажите что за тип у `AddDialog::fields`.

Comment: Ваша функция `refresh` вызывается в тот момент, когда `fields` пустой. А вы этого никак не проверяете. `qDebug() << fields.size() << fields[0];` - пытаетесь прочитать первый элемент массива, даже не убедившись, что он существует.
Почему функция вызывается в тот момент, когда `fields` пустой - это уже другой вопрос, по вашему примеру кода этого понять невозможно.

Comment: @ヒミコ, `QStringList` - это алиас на `QList<QString>`, но да, я с вами согласен, надо уже выбрать что-то одно.

Comment: @Ternvein, Алиас, или наследник? `QStringList inherits from QList<QString>. Like QList, QStringList is implicitly shared. It provides fast index-based access as well as fast insertions and removals. Passing string lists as value parameters is both fast and safe.`.

Comment: @ヒミコ, раньше был просто алиас через `typedef QList<QString> QStringList`. Возможно уже переделали.